# Create a generic path along with a specific one in openapi v3

Tags: node.js, swagger, openapi

I'm using express-openapi npm module for node.js server. I need for that purpose to create a generic url using openapi v3 like this one /ressources/{action} that would include all types of actions expect a few that I described specificly as /ressources/action1 and /ressources/action2 
Here how I described the generic parameter in url's path:

```
    action:
      name: action
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
        not:
          enum: ['action1', 'action2']
```

The specific urls are described seperatly without path parameter.

The issue is that whenever I launch the server and call for example /ressources/action1 it calls the generic url. I think there is an issue with the generic action path parameter enumeration. Can someone help figure out how to correctly match my request with the appropriate url in this situation ?

I also tried to enumerate all generic possible actions like this:

```
    action:
      name: action
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
        enum: ['action3', 'action4', 'action5', 'action6']
```

but action1 and action2 always matches the generic url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both definitions are correct, and according to the [OpenAPI Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#paths-object):

> When matching URLs, concrete (non-templated) paths would be matched before their templated counterparts.
>
> ...
>
> **Path Templating Matching**
>
> Assuming the following paths, the concrete definition, `/pets/mine`, will be matched first if used:
>
> ```
> /pets/{petId}
> /pets/mine
> ```

The fact that the server always picks up the generic URL is a bug (or unimplemented feature?). You should open an issue with whatever server framework you are using.

Comment: The problem is that both definitions are picked, the concrete one first, but also the generic second.. this way the treatement is done twice.. is this what it should behave like?

Comment: No it's an issue with the backend framework that you are using. Open a support ticket with the vendor of that framework.

Comment: Thanks Helen, I'll create a ticket