# Priority of paths in Open API 3

Tags: node.js, swagger, openapi, express-openapi-validator

I'm using an openapi validator (`express-openapi-validator`) in my Node.js project and can't figure out how to control the order of the paths matched.

If I have 2 paths such as,

```
/foo/{type}
   parameters:
     - name: type
       schema:
          type: string
          enum: ['bar', 'bam']
```

and

```
/foo/bar
```

For a request to `/foo/bar`, the second path is always matched.

How do I control the precedence of this match?

Comment: Related: [Create a generic path along with a specific one in OpenAPI v3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55562428/113116), [Are those OpenAPI 3 paths ambiguous?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67382759/113116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For a request to `/foo/bar`, the second path is always matched.

This is the correct and expected behavior. OpenAPI Specification states that specific paths must be matched before similar templated paths - see [Path Templating Matching](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3.html#path-templating-matching). This is not supposed to be configurable, otherwise the behavior would contradict the specification.

To have requests to `/foo/bar` handled by `/foo/{type}`, you'll need to remove the `/foo/bar` path from the API definition.